# Generate .so files?

Tags: android, android-ndk, android-emulator, .so

Hi developers I have question regarding generating .so files. And my app keeps stopping. Can anyone have the answer?
These are the steps I had undergone so far:

1. I have created an empty project in android studio.
2. created JNI Directory in project package.
3. created ADD.C file in JNI Directory
4. similarly Android.mk and Application.mk
5. intiated NDK-build statement and generated .so libs.
6. after running the Android app keeps stopping.

you can see my code.

[Android.mk file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0GHGW.png)

[ADD.C file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QhIP0.png)

[my java Main Activity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/biykg.png)

Comment: Well, what does the stacktrace say? Also, don't post screenshots of code; edit the actual code into your question.

Answer (score 0):

Try starting with https://github.com/android/ndk-samples/tree/main/hello-jni and see if you can get that to run successfully.